# How to speed up this code with NMaximize?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, finance

I want to maximize the expected exponential growth rate of the portfolio, which contains 3 stocks.

I get the adjusted stock price for General Electric, Du Pont, and IBM.

```
ge =  FinancialData["GE",  {{1962, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][[All, 2]];
dd =  FinancialData["DD",  {{1962, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][[All, 2]];
ibm = FinancialData["IBM", {{1962, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][[All, 2]];
```

The time step for a trading day, `dt`, is usually set at 1/252. To be more accurate, I set it as:

```
dt = (2015 - 1962 + 1)/Length@ge;
```

The realized continuously compounded returns, for 3 stocks, are calculated as follows:

```
{uge, udd, uibm} = Map[Log[Drop[#, 1]/Drop[#, -1]]/dt &, {ge, dd, ibm}];
```

Then I get the joint probability density function by interloping using the `SmoothKernelDistribution`:

```
pdfmulti = PDF[
   SmoothKernelDistribution[
     Transpose[{uge, udd, uibm}], 
     "LeastSquaresCrossValidation", "Gaussian"
   ]]
```

Let `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` be the fraction of the capital spend on GE, DD, IBM. The expected exponential growth rate, `G` is calculated using the integral,

```
G[f1_?NumericQ, f2_?NumericQ, f3_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
    Log[1 + f1 (Exp[u1 dt] - 1) + f2 (Exp[u2 dt] - 1) + f3 ( Exp[u3 dt] - 1)] pdfmulti[{u1, u2, u3}], 
    {u1, -70, 70}, {u2, -70, 70}, {u3, -70, 70}
  ]
```

Then, I tried to maximize `G` with respect to `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, by using `NMaximize`

```
NMaximize[
  {G[f1, f2, f3], f1 >= 0 && f2 >= 0 && f3 >= 0 && f1 + f2 + f3 <= 1},
  {f1, f2, f3}, PrecisionGoal -> 5
]
```

It took a whole day, and still didn't finish computing. The error code returns are:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.0002857958024361732 `and 0.000010590285788411786` for the integral and error estimates. >>

Is there any way I could speed up this algorithm? (I thought the problem is probably that there is an interpolating function `pdfmulti` in `NMaximize`. )

Comment: I think the problem is actually in the evaluation of `G`; in particular the `NIntegrate` integrand seems difficult to handle. Even trying to plot a contour surface of that function for specified values of the $f_i$ parameters takes a long time: `With[{f1 = 0.2, f2 = 0.7, f3 = 0.1},
 ContourPlot3D[
  Log[1 + f1 (Exp[u1 dt] - 1) + f2 (Exp[u2 dt] - 1) + 
     f3 (Exp[u3 dt] - 1)] pdfmulti[{u1, u2, u3}],
  {u1, -70, 70}, {u2, -70, 70}, {u3, -70, 70},
  PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 1
  ]
 ]`. Perhaps you should consider some other form of interpolation of your PDF.

Comment: @MarcoB , thanks for replying. I tried to assume these assets are uncorrelated, where the joint pdf will just be the product of 3 known pdf of normal distribution, and the maximization only took about 10 seconds. However, the assumption of uncorrelation is obviously not real. Also, I finally get the result `{0.000564953, {f1 -> 0.64713, f2 -> 0.176498, f3 -> 0.17448}}` after more than 12 hours of running. I'm learning `CopulaDistribution` to try to improve the code. Do you think it would help?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't help you there. That's outside of my field of expertise. Perhaps asking on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) might help reformulate the problem.

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, too long to put in a comment...

What I would suggest is to use smaller precision goals and restrain `NIntegrate`'s adaptive algorithm. This way you can get an answer in a relatively short time, analyze does it make sense, and continue with refinements that require more computational time.

The code below produces results under 35s on my laptop.

```
ge = FinancialData["GE", {{1962, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][[All, 2]];
dd = FinancialData["DD", {{1962, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][[All, 2]];
ibm = FinancialData["IBM", {{1962, 01, 01}, {2015, 12, 31}}][[All, 2]];

dt = (2015 - 1962 + 1)/Length@ge;

{uge, udd, uibm} = 
  Map[Log[Drop[#, 1]/Drop[#, -1]]/dt &, {ge, dd, ibm}];

pdfmulti = 
  PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[Transpose[{uge, udd, uibm}], 
    "LeastSquaresCrossValidation", "Gaussian"]];

G[f1_?NumericQ, f2_?NumericQ, f3_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Log[1 + f1 (Exp[u1 dt] - 1) + f2 (Exp[u2 dt] - 1) + 
     f3 (Exp[u3 dt] - 1)] pdfmulti[{u1, u2, u3}], {u1, -70, 
   70}, {u2, -70, 70}, {u3, -70, 70}, MinRecursion -> 1, 
  MaxRecursion -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

AbsoluteTiming[
 NMaximize[{G[f1, f2, f3], 
   f1 >= 0 && f2 >= 0 && f3 >= 0 && f1 + f2 + f3 <= 1}, {f1, f2, f3}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3]
 ]

(* {32.2225, {0.00346539, {f1 -> 0.656504, f2 -> 0.32803, 
   f3 -> 0.0154653}}} *)
```

### Update

My suggestion might not be that applicable. Here are the results with different `NIntegrate` options that have little to do with the results above:

```
G[f1_?NumericQ, f2_?NumericQ, f3_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Log[1 + f1 (Exp[u1 dt] - 1) + f2 (Exp[u2 dt] - 1) + 
     f3 (Exp[u3 dt] - 1)] pdfmulti[{u1, u2, u3}], {u1, -70, 
   70}, {u2, -70, 70}, {u3, -70, 70}, MinRecursion -> 2, 
  MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
    "SingularityHandler" -> None}]

AbsoluteTiming[
 NMaximize[{G[f1, f2, f3], 
   f1 >= 0 && f2 >= 0 && f3 >= 0 && f1 + f2 + f3 <= 1}, {f1, f2, f3}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3]
 ]

(* {887.217, {0.00057827, {f1 -> 0.815837, f2 -> 0.0288783, 
   f3 -> 0.155158}}} *)
```

Comment: @haijiaxuan Great, good luck!